# Is it OK to have a php form destination rely on session variables?

Tags: php, security, session

I hope the title makes sense. I have a sort of social-networking site where on the profile page a HTML form will be submitted to a php file which will store the user input in a MySQL database using the username session variable created at the login, right now a simplified version looks like this:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method='POST' action='destination.php'>
            <input type='text' name='email'/>
            <input type='text' name='location'/>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
        </form>
    <body>
</html>
```

destination.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'] //from before (e.g. login)

//CONNECT TO MYSQL
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$sqlusername = "root";
$sqlpassword = "*********";
$dbname = "**********";


$conn =  new mysqli($servername, $sqlusername, $sqlpassword, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = $conn->prepare("insert into users(email, location) values(?, ?) where username=?");
$sql->bind_param("sss", $_POST['email'], $_POST['location'], $username);
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

This works great, however I am running it on a developing machine and was wondering how it would actually work when multiple users will be posting forms at almost the same time, will the session get 'confused'? I am new at all this so I am not exactly sure how sessions work but is the above code safe? If not what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sessions work by creating a unique identification(UID) number for each
>   visitor and storing variables based on this ID. This helps to prevent
>   two users' data from getting confused with one another when visiting
>   the same webpage.

**When a session is started following things happen −**

> PHP first creates a unique identifier for that particular session
>   which is a random string of 32 hexadecimal numbers such as
>   3c7foj34c3jj973hjkop2fc937e3443.
>
> A cookie called PHPSESSID is automatically sent to the user's computer
>   to store unique session identification string.
>
> A file is automatically created on the server in the designated
>   temporary directory and bears the name of the unique identifier
>   prefixed by sess_ ie sess_3c7foj34c3jj973hjkop2fc937e3443.
>
> When a PHP script wants to retrieve the value from a session variable,
>   PHP automatically gets the unique session identifier string from the
>   PHPSESSID cookie and then looks in its temporary directory for the
>   file bearing that name and a validation can be done by comparing both
>   values.